# Unable to find /oauth/device/code Auth0 Java API

Tags: java, go, auth0

Is there an API to fetch the device code via Auth0 Java API, we use the following snippet in Go, the question is if there is a standard API or should we make a HTTP request call

```go
url := "https://dev-foo.us.auth0.com/oauth/device/code"

payload := strings.NewReader("client_id=RO6N7mr&scope=openid&audience=https://dev-foo.us.auth0.com/api/v2/")

req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", url, payload)
```

Comment: you can check out this blog: https://auth0.com/developers/hub/code-samples/api/spring-functional-java/basic-authorization, has good examples on the same

Comment: there is nothing specific to what I am looking for @DebDas

Comment: Do you mean that you are searching a go package for client oauth2 access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#get-device-code) tells you that you need to send a POST request like the following:

> POST https://YOUR_DOMAIN/oauth/device/code

> Content-Type:

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&scope=SCOPE&audience=API_IDENTIFIER

and the response would look like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "device_code":"GmRh...k9eS",
  "user_code":"WDJB-MJHT",
  "verification_uri":"https://YOUR_DOMAIN/device",
  "verification_uri_complete":"https://YOUR_DOMAIN/device?user_code=WDJB-MJHT",
  "expires_in":900, //in seconds
  "interval":5
}
```

[image]